# Create InputRadioGroups in a loop in Play 2.4

Tags: java, html, forms, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am looking for a way to create `inputRadioGroup`s with different names and values in a for loop.

For example, I have a list of 10 applicants. index.scala.html displays every applicant's name and offers 3 radio buttons (hire, decline, maybe) to the user.

This is what I got so far. The problem is, that every group has the same names, values and Ids. So I can select only one of 30 options (and I, of course, want to select 10, 1 per group). Furthermore, how can I change the code in a way that I can work with the results of every selection?

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.save(), 'id -> "userForm") {
<fieldset>
    @for(applicant <- applicants) {
    <hr>
    <h3>@applicant.getName()</h3>
    <h4>Decision</h4>
    @helper.inputRadioGroup( userForm("status"), options =
    Seq("hire"->"Hire", "decline"->"Decline", "maybe"->"Maybe"), '_label ->
    "Language", '_error ->
    userForm("status").error.map(_.withMessage("select something"))) 
    }
</fieldset>
<div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: The best way is to use custom HTML input as describe here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaFormHelpers

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.save(), 'id -> "userForm") {
<fieldset>
    @for(applicant <- applicants) {
    <hr>
    <h3>@applicant.getName()</h3>
            <h4>Decision</h4>

            @helper.input(userForm("status")) { (id,name,value,args) =>
            <div class="radio">
                <label> <input type="radio"
                    name="name_@applicant.getId" id="option1_id_@applicant.getId"
                    value="value1" @toHtmlArgs(args)>Hire
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label> <input type="radio"
                    name="name_@applicant.getId" id="option2_id_@applicant.getId"
                    value="value2" @toHtmlArgs(args)> Fire
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label> <input type="radio"
                    name="name_@applicant.getId" id="option3_id_@applicant.getId"
                    value="value3" @toHtmlArgs(args)> Maybe
                </label>
            </div>
            }
    }
</fieldset>
<div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">
</div>
}
```